# Run SSIS programmatically, remotely, and without a Windows or Web Service... maybe with Powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, ssis, remoting

I'm working on a project where the client Company has one Enterprise SQL Server license and its box is highly exclusive.  I need the Enterprise version because the package uses fuzzy lookups.

So I want to trigger the launch of the package remotely from some VB.Net code.  I can't use the DTS Runtime library because they require the calling box to be running the Enterprise version too; besides Enterpise is version 2012 while everywhere else is SQL 2008 R2.  I can't install either a web service or a Windows Service on the Enterprise machine to call an SSIS package because the client won't let me.  I could create a job but I don't know how to trigger it on-demand.

I've read that Powershell is the answer but the script I've written generates an invoke command that runs DTExec which doesn't work as again I don't have the Enterprise version installed locally.  Can anybody point me to the solution?  I've looked and looked and all I find is variations on what I've already tried and know won't work.

Cheers

Comment: do you have sql server agent service running? Look into sp_run_job. Setup a Job and run it with that stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response mxix.  I've tried sp_run_job however I also need to pass some parameters and I don't think this is supported.  I should have mentioned this.  Sorry.

Comment: You can setup your package/job to read those parameters from a table.
Update the table, run the job. In case of SSIS, you can Setup SSIS_Config_table and have the package read from it. In Deployment mode if you have a catalog setup your package with parameters, and config an enviorement. Change the Enviorement, run the package. There are many options. =)

Comment: Again thanks mxix.  Ya, I'm not allowed to add tables to the Enterpise server at all.  The package connects to remote tables and the connections used are what the parameters are about.  So this is a chicken and the egg problem.

But you're giving me pause to think.  If I put the parameters in a config file, then modify that config file right before calling the package, it ought to work.  Something tells me that I tried this and ran into a different issue but maybe not.  I'll take another look.